# Probability to iteratively and independently remove $n$ elements until all gone

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, algorithms, random-variables, recursive-algorithms

The problem is as follows:

> Let S be a set of n elements. At the first stage each element in S is
>   in- dependently removed with probability p. Those elements not removed
>   constitute the set S1. If S1 is not the empty set then each of its
>   ele- ments is independently removed with probability p, with the
>   remaining elements constituting the set S2, and so on. Let N be the
>   least k such that Sk is empty. Give a formula for the probability that
>   N = r. Hint: N can be expressed as the maximum of a set of independent
>   geometric random variables.

Here's my thought so far: let 1st element attain the max, then
$P(N = r) = P(X_1 = r) \prod_{i = 2}^n P(X_i <= r)$, where the $X_i \sim Geom(p)$. However, I'm unsure of the above as there isn't a rigorous chain of steps that I'm following.

**EDIT:** The following is my latest thought which seems more correct than the above. Let $k$ denote the number of elements that survive until the last round. Then,
$P(N = r) = \sum_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} [P(X = r)]^k [P(X < r)]^{n - k}$, where $X \sim Geom(p)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the elements of $S$ be $s_1$ to $s_n$. For $i=1$ to $n$, define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i$ is the number of steps until $s_i$ is removed. Then $X_i$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p$. The number $N$ of steps until all the $s_i$ are gone is then $\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.

The probability that $X_i$ is $\gt r$ is $(1-p)^r$, so the probability that $N\gt r$ is $(1-p)^{rn}$, which is $((1-p)^n)^r$. It follows that $N$ has geometric distribution with parameter $1-(1-p)^n$.

Comment: I don't follow why obtaining $P(N > r) = ((1-p)^n)^r$ directly concludes $N$ follows a geometric distribution. The only similar results I know of are to compare moment generating functions (or moments) to assert two random variables have the same distribution; here it seems to me it's only comparing the probability?

Comment: It is simpler than that. Suppose $\Pr(N\gt r)=a^r$. Then $\Pr(N=r)=\Pr(N\gt r-1)-\Pr(N\gt r)=a^{r-1}-a^r=a^{r-1}(1-a)$. This is the distribution function of the geometric parameter $b=1-a$, for $\Pr(N=r)=(1-b)^{r-1} b$.

Comment: That makes total sense; thank you. Could you also take a look at my solution inside "EDIT"? I couldn't figure it out why it's wrong.

Comment: At a casual glance, it does not look wrong, but certainly far more complicated-looking than the simple answer above. May be able to evaluate more precisely after the (very long) Executive election meeting this afternoon.

Comment: I wrote a Python program to test that my formula yields different numbers than yours, so there must be some issues in my solution that I still haven't spotted. Marking this as accepted in the meantime; would appreciate a lot if you could take a closer look.